# Jabra Microphones not Enabled in ubuntu 19.10 msi

Tags: sound, 19.10, microphone, msi

I am unable to use my microphones as an input device though the output configuration is working fine in ubuntu 19.10.
Headphones model is jabra evolve 20 c with mic

**Things I did**

I have checked input in windows/mac it is working fine where as for ubuntu 19.10 it didn't.
I also used alsamixer and did the apt configurations (screenshot below).
I also used pavucontrol and specified the configuration as Analalog Sterio Output and for input  (mentioned in the screenshot) because of this too the input is not getting shown.

I checked my output configurations and also used alsamixer to correct some configurations but still no luck. 
I have also tried various other solutions and still had hard luck.

Can anyone guide me on how to debug this issue and correct the same?

[alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC1oR.png)
[system sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnCu4.png)
[pavucontrol settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt9nx.png)

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months

Comment: FYI:  Main Ubuntu releases that rely on deb packages like server/desktop use a *yy.mm* format, the *yy* format is used by specialist releases that rely on snap packages but only come out in even years such as Ubuntu Core, and there is no Ubuntu 19, so if your system claims to be Ubuntu 19, you're not using Ubuntu at all.

Comment: @guiverc Edited the message .

Comment: Is it a bluetooth or a wired microphone? Part of a headset? If BT by default these only get an "output" profile IIRC.

Comment: @xenoid Edited the message and it has a wired microphone.